# How do you remove the Wiki & Tickets from Trac?

Tags: trac

we use only the source browser part of the app.

I tried poking around in the conf.ini but with no luck

Answer (score 1):

There is a [FAQ](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFaq#we-re-already-using-bugzilla-can-i-disable-tickets) entry for disabling tickets. Don't know if you can disable the wiki functionality.

Comment: You should be able to disable the `trac.wiki` module the same way.

Comment: In Trac 1.4.3, just disable all `trac.wiki.*` except `DefaultWikiPolicy`.